# trigger and execute a request in back end php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, curl, phpmailer

I'm using Amazon web server.. I have a function for mail like below,

```
function mail_send($to){
  require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
  require_once("class.smtp.php");
  $mail->AddAddress($to);
  $mail->Send();
}
```

Whenever I want to send mail, I'm just calling this function by,

```
mail_send("example@xyz.com");
```

So, if I'm trying to send mail in loop, this will take more time to send mail.. approximately it will take 5 seconds for sending each mail.. But in aws, maximum execution time is 60 seconds in browser, after that it shows empty response... So, I need to trigger the mail and it need to be executed in backend. So, if I'm sending mail to 10 members, It need to only trigger the mail function for 10 times and the page loading should be stopped..

I have tried CURL, But it also waits for response of sending each mail so, it will taking same time to execute

Comment: If mail content is same for all users, why not to send one email with all users in BCC instead of using loop?

Comment: @Dmitri Mail content is same, but not for users, They're clients. I have to send mail to each clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send from a cron script or other scheduled task that does not have a timeout - search on here for how to do that.

Send more efficiently - see [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Get your local mail server to work for you - submit messages to it (which will be very fast) and let it deal with slow deliveries - it's what mail servers are for.

I can see you've based your code on an obsolete example and are using an old version of PHPMailer, so [get the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).